# GMSMarker infowindow content(snippet) not updating

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I have an array in which each element has `Latitude` `Longitude` and some other values in it to draw marker on map. I'm using the following code to update the snippet, position and icon of `GMSMarker`. I'm using a `UISlider` to iterate through the array. When I do this the icon and position of the marker gets updated and the `InfoWindow` of the marker not updating. It shows only the old content. But when I deselect and select it again now it shows correct infowindow content. I have tried to use `tracksInfoWindowChanges`, but it's not working.

```
 @IBAction func progressChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    let iVal = Int(sender.value)

    if iVal < progressList.count {
        let str = progressList[iVal]
        let arr = str.components(separatedBy: "!")
        let lat = Double(arr[4])!
        let lng = Double(arr[5])!
        let pos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
        let fRotation = Float(arr[9])
        let rotation = CGFloat(fRotation!)
        let strTime = arr[0]
        let idleFlag = arr[1]
        let strSpeed = arr[2]
        let strName = arr[3]

        proMarker.position = pos
        proMarker.title = strName

        if idleFlag == "Y" {
            proMarker.snippet = strSpeed + "!" + strTime + "!" + "idle"
            proMarker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true

            let markerImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_red")
            let rotated = markerImage?.imageRotatedByDegrees(rotation, flip: false)

            proMarker.icon = rotated

        } else {
            proMarker.snippet = strSpeed + "!" + strTime + "!" + "moving"
            proMarker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true

            let markerImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_green")
            let rotated = markerImage?.imageRotatedByDegrees(rotation, flip: false)

            proMarker.icon = rotated
        }

        proMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        let dTime = sdf5.date(from: strTime)
        let sTime = sdf6.string(from: dTime!)

        hTime.text = sTime
        hSpeedIdle.text = strSpeed + " km/h"

    }

}
```

Please help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to add lat_long, You should add marker_obj into array because each marker contain all related info, and it can help you to reduce such type of length of code.

Comment: that's not the problem here. Marker location and icon updates without any problem. Only the infowindow not updating.

Comment: Ok, try to  create new instance of `proMarker` inside if{} condition.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, it may be that you are not making new markers, or if you are, you need to remove the map from the old markers (`marker.map = nil`). So when you click on overlapped markers, the infowindows will sequentially appear.